# custom button with inconsistent visibility

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

The EditCommandButton style defined below is showing odd behavior; it only shows for the last instance defined (next to the Avatar label below).

I tried making the style x:Shared="true" and using DynamicResource but with the same result.

I do eventually want the button to invisible until request, which is why you see a trigger for that. But until I figure this out I just have the default visibility at visible.

Can someone explain this behavior and offer a fix?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Design View

[image]

## Runtime View

[image]

## Button Style

```
<Style x:Key="EditCommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="a" Foreground="Navy" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontSize="24" Width="30"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="theBorder" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="theContent" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectedSatelliteVm.EditCommand}"/>
</Style>
```

## Usage

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonInfoEditingControlTemplate">

    <Grid>

        ...

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ... />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource EditCommandButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock .../>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ... />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource EditCommandButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock .../>

        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  .../>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource EditCommandButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ... />

    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

## EDIT for Rachel

Look Ma, no triggers! Only the last button shows the arrow though...

```
<Style x:Key="TestCommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="a" Foreground="Navy" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontSize="24" Width="30"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectedSatelliteVm.EditCommand}"/>
</Style>
```

[image]

## the FIX

```
<Style x:Key="EditCommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="a" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Wingdings 3" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectedSatelliteVm.EditCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="theBorder" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="theContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style as originally written actually had two problems, both fixed by the style above. (by fixed I mean it works as intended, not that it is the 'right' way to do it!):

1. DP Precedence - this is what Rachel's answer is addressing although her answer. But the only effective fix I found is to set visibility using two triggers for IsMouseOver as shown.
2. Only the last item in the Grid was showing any content! - this one makes no sense to me, but moving the properties previously in the TextBlock content to Setters on the style fixes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencey properties defined in the `<Tag>` have a higher precedence than items defined in triggers, so will always overwrite them.

For example, in this case the button's `Visibility` will always be `Collapsed` regardless of what the trigger is, because the property is defined in the `<Button>` tag

```
<Button Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Property="{Binding SomeValue}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

To make this trigger work, move the `Visibility` property to a Style Setter, which has a lower precedence than a Style Trigger, so triggered values will overwrite it

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Property="{Binding SomeValue}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

See MSDN's [Dependency Property Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) for more information

**Edit**

As for your second problem about the Content only showing up once, I suspect it is because you have the `Content` bound in your style, and not the `ContentTemplate`.

WPF is creating a single instance of the `TextBlock` arrow, and a control can only have one parent, so after the style is applied, so only one `Button` can contain the arrow `TextBlock`

The fix is to use the `ContentTemplate` property instead of the `Content` property.

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="a" Foreground="Navy" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontSize="24" Width="30"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Honestly, I'm surprised it didn't give you an error about `Specified element is already the logical child of another element`. That is usually what happens in these kind of cases (see my post [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/wpf-error-specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it-first/) for more details)

Comment: Useful info for sure, but this isn't explaining or solving my original problem. Pls see last EDIT. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl You have a `Visibility` trigger on `theContent`

Comment: NO, that last edit has a style ("TestCommandButtonStyle") with no triggers and no visibility property settings. This is a strange one...

Comment: Close enough but the full fix for anyone else that gets stuck is at the end of the original post. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl I re-read your question this morning and updated my answer to include the probable cause of your second problem

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentTemplate' property on a Setter.

Comment: @Berryl You need to wrap it in a `<DataTemplate>` tag

Comment: I'm just missing something basic here. I made another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059944/style-content-via-setters-v-contenttemplate) to explain the latest problem better. Should be easy money for you :--)