# Style content via setters v ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, styles

The xaml for the first style works as I want, producing a button with a Wingding glyph using setters to lay out the content and it's properties. The second version of this style is trying to do the same thing but with a DataTemplate for the Content, but it just displays the type of a DataTemplate (ie, System.Windows.DataTemplate).

1. Why won't the 2nd version display the same content as the 1st?
2. Assuming the fix is trivial, would one version of the style be preferable over the other for any reason beyond personal preference?

NOTE: I am showing the bindings and triggers in case there is something in there that is affecting the content, but it's only the the first part of the style that varies

Cheers,
Berryl

## Style 1

Displays: [image]

```
<Style x:Key="EditCommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="a" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Wingdings 3" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />

    <!--What makes it an Edit button-->
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActivateThisSatelliteVmCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="HeaderLabel" StringFormat="{resx:Resx ResxName=Smack.Core.Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=Item_Edit_Label}"/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- WHen its available -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="theBorder" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="theContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## Style 2

Displays "System.Windows.DataTemplate"

```
<Style x:Key="EditCommandButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="a" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="Navy" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!--What makes it an Edit button-->
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActivateThisSatelliteVmCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding Path="HeaderLabel" StringFormat="{resx:Resx ResxName=Core.Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=Item_Edit_Label}"/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- When its available -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="theBorder" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="theContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="theBorder" Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is removing the wrapping DataTemplate from TextBlock solving the problem?

Comment: @LPL. No, without the DataTemplate wrap its a runtime error: Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.ContentTemplate' property on a Setter.

Comment: Removing the DataTemplate works for me.  You should just put your content into the content property.  No template required.

Comment: @Phil. That would lead to different problems when you try and use the style with multiple parents. See [Rachel's blog post for the gory details](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/wpf-error-specified-element-is-already-the-logical-child-of-another-element-disconnect-it-first/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `Content` property is set to a `DataTemplate`

`DataTemplates` are meant to be used with `Template` properties, and not directly inserted into the VisualTree via the `Content` property

Change your Style Setter to set the `ContentTemplate` instead of `Content` and it should work fine

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="a" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="Navy" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

As for your second question, I prefer the first because its simpler, and I think it may contain fewer elements in the Visual Tree (I'd have to double-check that)

Comment: Bingo, unsurprisingly. It confirms my suspicion that the WPF learning curve is surrprisingly steep when there is only a tiny handful of people that consistently have the answers to what should be mundane questions. Cheers

Comment: I also add to use a `<ContentPresenter />` in my parent template instead of `<ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />` for it to work but now I can't override the content in the view anymore. Making it not a overridable default value. (which was my initial goal)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to resolve this issue:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="BackBorder" Margin="0" Padding="0"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="FrontBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=BackBorder, Path=CornerRadius}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```